# [Random String Generator]Getting stuck in a loop on else condition

Tags: python, string, password-generator

So (as you will probably see from my code) I am a beginner at Python (version 3.8.3) and enjoying it very much so far, and I have challenged myself on several different beginner projects. I am currently making a random string generator (i.e. a password generator, hence the use of the secrets module).

```
# Password Generator
import secrets, string

print("Welcome to the generator. Please specify your requirements")
print("A. All Characters;\nB. No Numbers;\nC. No Punctuation\nPlease choose the appropriate letter for your needs.")
userInput = input()
def userWelcome():

  if userInput.lower() == "a":
      generatePass = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
      print("How long do you want your string to be?")
      stringRange = int(input())
      print( "".join(secrets.choice(generatePass) for _ in range(stringRange)) )


  elif userInput.lower() == "b":
      generatePass = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation
      print("How long do you want your string to be?")
      stringRange = int(input())
      print("".join(secrets.choice(generatePass) for _ in range(stringRange)))


  elif userInput.lower() == "c":
      generatePass = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
      print("How long do you want your string to be?")
      stringRange = int(input())
      print("".join(secrets.choice(generatePass) for _ in range(stringRange)))


  else:
      print("Not an option! Let's try again.")
      userWelcome()

userWelcome()
```

However, **my problem is what to do if the user inputs an incorrect option**. As you can see, with the else statement I assume what they filled in does not match any of the earlier options - and so I want to try to rerun the generator again (so I try to call userWelcome again in the else statement).

However, when I type in for example 12 as input, my shell starts to output my string (Not an option Let's try again) literally a thousand times like it is stuck in a loop. I am wondering what I am doing wrong exactly.

**What I have tried:**

(1) So I have tried to solve this input problem first with **try and except**, running the except when there is a ValueError but that only works for numbers and I did not manage to rerun userWelcome()

(2) I have tried to create a **elif statement** in which I check the input for integers, however that also gets stuck in a loop. Code:

```
elif userInput.isalpha() == False:
    print("Not an option! Let's try again.")
    userWelcome()
```

Anyway, I hope that explains it well. I have been busy with this for a few hours now and I thought I'd ask this. Maybe it's a very stupid question but for me it's hard :)

**TL;DR: Want to check for proper user input by running my function again, get stuck in weird loop**

Thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code calls `userWelcome()` recursively, without changing the global variable `userInput`. The same bad string is processed again, causing the same result, which again calls `userWelcome()` - for ever (at least until max call depth).

You should read a new string at the beginning of `userWelcome`, instead of using a global variable. Also, recursion here is an overkill that confuses you. Better use a simple while loop:

```
while True:
  userInput = ....
  if ....
     do something
     return
  elif ...
     do something else
     return  # exit the function - breaking out of the loop
  else:
     print(error message)
     # No return here, means the loop will continue to loop
```

If you want to call the function instead of  loop inside, you can instead make the function return success (True) vs. failure (False), and loop that in the caller:

```
while not userWelcome(inputString):
    inputString = read the string

def userWelcome(inputString):
   if inputString == ....:
      something
      return True # To mark OK
   elif inputString == .....:
      something else
      return True # To mark OK
   else:
      print an error
      return False # To mark failure
```

Just avoid global variables, it is a bad practice. Pass the value through parameters, as in the code above.

Comment: After thinking about what you said and trying it out for myself, I definitely understand now! A bit stupid of me in hind sight, but indeed recursion is what confused me in the end. Thanks!

Comment: @Merccii its OK. The best way to learn is to learn from mistakes.